# Failed to create Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, hector

It is simple to create a cluster with this line of code:

```
Cluster c = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("MyTest Cluster","localhost:9160");
```

compiled fine, when run, I got the following error. Appreciate for any suggestion.

> Error: [java] INFO connection.CassandraHostRetryService: Downed Host
>   Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
>        [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/thrift/InvalidRequestException
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.ConcurrentHClientPool.(ConcurrentHClientPool.java:48)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.RoundRobinBalancingPolicy.createConnection(RoundRobinBalancingPolicy.java:68)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.(HConnectionManager.java:65)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.(AbstractCluster.java:69)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.(AbstractCluster.java:65)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.(ThriftCluster.java:17)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.createCluster(HFactory.java:176)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:155)
>        [java]     at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:128)

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/thrift/InvalidRequestException [java] 
You should start from here, to get the jar file (apache-cassandra-thrift) that own this class and place in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks to all. I fixed it by adding all dependent jars.

Answer (score 0):

It's not finding thrift on your classpath.  If you're using Maven and Eclipse, you might expect to see this if you didn't include the cassandra-thrift dependency, or if you performed a recent mvn eclipse:eclipse and need to "refresh" your project.